# NgRoute not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

For some reason im not sure about my ngRoute here is not working properly. Please help me thankyou. **[Here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/fourm#openfile-README.md)** is my cloud9 file where you can see live preiview and edit code. And here is my script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('ChattApp', ["firebase", "ngRoute"])


app.config(["$routeProvider",  function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'HtmlFiles/login.html',
      controller : 'LoginController.js'
    })

    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'

    })
    //Talk In Chat/Group Chat. I have to go to school now..


}]
)

app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);
```

Comment: `not working properly` isn't a proper problem description. ALso that link requires logging in and is therefore worthless. Create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates problem

Comment: Are you loading the correct files?.. check if you don't have syntax error in LoginController.js

Comment: Provider your controller's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `app` definition in all controller files.. as `app` is already defined in another script.. the cause is that the variable is being redefined for each loaded controller file..

please check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for variable scope lifetimes

Answer (score 0):

Controller inside the object for the ".when" method takes controller name which is registered via angular not a 'js' file containing the controller's code.
  When you register the controller you use the method `Controller(name, constructor)`.  Then name you place as the first argument is the "name" of the controller that you are registering with angular.

`controller : 'LoginController.js'`
Should be:
`controller : 'LoginController'`

References: [Route Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), [Controller Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#controller)

Search for "Route" on this page and then look at the controller object properties.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation as to where "name" come's from.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did: app.controller('LoginController', ["$firebaseAuth", "$scope", function(){
}]
)

Comment: No for the Route you need the controller set to the controllers "name".  You have ```controller : 'LoginController.js'``` in the code above.  It needs to be ```controller: 'LoginController'```